# Cuda version issue while using Detectron2 in Google Colab

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run the Detectron2 module on Colab using CUDA version 10.0 but since today there have been some issues regarding the versions of Cuda Compiler.

The output I get after running `!nvidia-smi` is :

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.36.06    Driver Version: 418.67       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   36C    P0    26W / 250W |      0MiB / 16280MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                 ERR! |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And what I get after running `!nvcc --version` is :

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130
```

I am not able to understand the reason for the mismatch. Also the output from detectron after running `!python -m detectron2.utils.collect_env` is :

```
----------------------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
sys.platform            linux
Python                  3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) [GCC 8.4.0]
numpy                   1.18.5
detectron2              0.1.3 @/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/Table_Struct/detectron2_repo/detectron2
Compiler                GCC 7.5
CUDA compiler           CUDA 10.1
detectron2 arch flags   sm_60
DETECTRON2_ENV_MODULE   <not set>
PyTorch                 1.4.0+cu100 @/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch
PyTorch debug build     False
GPU available           True
GPU 0                   Tesla K80
CUDA_HOME               /usr/local/cuda
Pillow                  7.0.0
torchvision             0.5.0+cu100 @/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision
torchvision arch flags  sm_35, sm_50, sm_60, sm_70, sm_75
fvcore                  0.1.1
cv2                     4.1.2
----------------------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
PyTorch built with:
  - GCC 7.3
  - Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2019.0.4 Product Build 20190411 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications
  - Intel(R) MKL-DNN v0.21.1 (Git Hash 7d2fd500bc78936d1d648ca713b901012f470dbc)
  - OpenMP 201511 (a.k.a. OpenMP 4.5)
  - NNPACK is enabled
  - CUDA Runtime 10.0
  - NVCC architecture flags: -gencode;arch=compute_37,code=sm_37;-gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=sm_70;-gencode;arch=compute_75,code=sm_75;-gencode;arch=compute_37,code=compute_37
  - CuDNN 7.6.3
  - Magma 2.5.1
  - Build settings: BLAS=MKL, BUILD_NAMEDTENSOR=OFF, BUILD_TYPE=Release, CXX_FLAGS= -Wno-deprecated -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fopenmp -DUSE_FBGEMM -DUSE_QNNPACK -DUSE_PYTORCH_QNNPACK -O2 -fPIC -Wno-narrowing -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-type-limits -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-result -Wno-strict-overflow -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-error=pedantic -Wno-error=redundant-decls -Wno-error=old-style-cast -fdiagnostics-color=always -faligned-new -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-math-errno -fno-trapping-math -Wno-stringop-overflow, DISABLE_NUMA=1, PERF_WITH_AVX=1, PERF_WITH_AVX2=1, PERF_WITH_AVX512=1, USE_CUDA=ON, USE_EXCEPTION_PTR=1, USE_GFLAGS=OFF, USE_GLOG=OFF, USE_MKL=ON, USE_MKLDNN=ON, USE_MPI=OFF, USE_NCCL=ON, USE_NNPACK=ON, USE_OPENMP=ON, USE_STATIC_DISPATCH=OFF,
```

My guess is that the version of CUDA on Colab doesn't match the Detectron2 I am using. IF so how can I change something to make this work on Google Colab.

Comment: There is no mismatch. The driver is telling you (via nvidia-smi) what the maximum cuda version it supports. Nothing more. You are trying to solve a problem which does not exist

Comment: Then my pytorch build for Cuda 10.0 should work right ? But I get the error 'RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device'

Comment: I can't comment about PyTorch. If that is what you question is actually about, then make it a PyTorch question

Comment: I believe it is due to a mismatch between the Pytorch and CUDA version. The pytorch is built for CUDA version 10.0 but the system is not providing that environment.

Comment: CUDA toolkit version maybe, not CUDA driver. This isn't a CUDA programming related question -- it is about getting PyTorch to run on colab, which I don't think is really on topic for  [SO]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the compiled Detectron2 Cuda runtime version and once I recompiled Detectron2 the error was solved.

Here is the result from `!python -m detectron2.utils.collect_env` command:

```
----------------------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
sys.platform            linux
Python                  3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) [GCC 8.4.0]
numpy                   1.18.5
detectron2              0.1.3 @/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/Table_Struct/detectron2_repo/detectron2
Compiler                GCC 7.5
CUDA compiler           CUDA 10.0
detectron2 arch flags   sm_75
DETECTRON2_ENV_MODULE   <not set>
PyTorch                 1.4.0+cu100 @/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch
PyTorch debug build     False
GPU available           True
GPU 0                   Tesla T4
CUDA_HOME               /usr/local/cuda
Pillow                  7.0.0
torchvision             0.5.0+cu100 @/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision
torchvision arch flags  sm_35, sm_50, sm_60, sm_70, sm_75
fvcore                  0.1.1
cv2                     4.1.2
----------------------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
PyTorch built with:
  - GCC 7.3
  - Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2019.0.4 Product Build 20190411 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications
  - Intel(R) MKL-DNN v0.21.1 (Git Hash 7d2fd500bc78936d1d648ca713b901012f470dbc)
  - OpenMP 201511 (a.k.a. OpenMP 4.5)
  - NNPACK is enabled
  - CUDA Runtime 10.0
  - NVCC architecture flags: -gencode;arch=compute_37,code=sm_37;-gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=sm_70;-gencode;arch=compute_75,code=sm_75;-gencode;arch=compute_37,code=compute_37
  - CuDNN 7.6.3
  - Magma 2.5.1
  - Build settings: BLAS=MKL, BUILD_NAMEDTENSOR=OFF, BUILD_TYPE=Release, CXX_FLAGS= -Wno-deprecated -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fopenmp -DUSE_FBGEMM -DUSE_QNNPACK -DUSE_PYTORCH_QNNPACK -O2 -fPIC -Wno-narrowing -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-type-limits -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-result -Wno-strict-overflow -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-error=pedantic -Wno-error=redundant-decls -Wno-error=old-style-cast -fdiagnostics-color=always -faligned-new -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-math-errno -fno-trapping-math -Wno-stringop-overflow, DISABLE_NUMA=1, PERF_WITH_AVX=1, PERF_WITH_AVX2=1, PERF_WITH_AVX512=1, USE_CUDA=ON, USE_EXCEPTION_PTR=1, USE_GFLAGS=OFF, USE_GLOG=OFF, USE_MKL=ON, USE_MKLDNN=ON, USE_MPI=OFF, USE_NCCL=ON, USE_NNPACK=ON, USE_OPENMP=ON, USE_STATIC_DISPATCH=OFF,
```